# Loading bar from Waiter package doesn't disappear after its use [SHINY]

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny app and I have started using the `Waiter` package.
When I load the app, before doing anything, we cannot see anything (at it is expected). When I generate the plot, the loading bar appears but when it finishes, it doesn't disappear. It stays a white box that it still can be seen.

Loading....
[image: image1]

It has finished.
[image: image 2]

Does anyone know how to remove it?

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(waiter)

new_choices <- setNames(names(mtcars), names(mtcars))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("My shiny app"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Selection",
                  selectInput("x_axis", "Choose x axis",
                            choices = new_choices),
                  
                  selectInput("y_axis", "Choose y axis",
                              choices = new_choices),
               
                  hr(),
                ),
                  
          tabPanel("Titles",
                    hr(),
              
                    textInput(inputId = "title", "You can write the title:",  value = "This is the title"),
                    textInput(inputId = "xlab", "You can re-name the x-axis:",  value = "x-axis...."),
                    textInput(inputId = "ylab", "You can re-name the y-axis:",  value = "y-axis ...."),
          
                  ),
      
      
          tabPanel("Calculations", 
                    hr(),
                    
                    checkboxInput("log2", "Do the log2 transformation", value = F),
                    checkboxInput("sqrt", "Calculate the square root", value = F),
                   
                   )

          ),
      useWaitress(),
      actionButton(inputId = "drawplot", label = "Show the plot")
    
      ),
              
              # Show a plot of the generated distribution
              mainPanel(
                plotOutput("plot"),
              )
      )
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  waitress <- Waitress$new(theme = "overlay-percent", min = 0, max = 10)
  
  data <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })
  
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data <- data()
    if(input$log2 == TRUE){
      data <- log2(data+1)
    }
    if(input$sqrt == TRUE){
      data <- sqrt(data)
    }
    return(data)
    
  })
  
  
  v <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$drawplot, {
    
    # use notification
    waitress$notify()
    
    for(i in 1:10){
      waitress$inc(1) # increase by 10%
      Sys.sleep(.3)
    }
    
    v$plot <- ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = filtered_data(),
                 aes_string(x = input$x_axis, y = input$y_axis)) +
      xlab(input$xlab) +
      ylab(input$ylab) +
      ggtitle(input$title)
    
    waitress$close() # hide when done
    
  })
  
  

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(v$plot)) return()
    v$plot
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like a bug to me. You may file an issue to the waiter github repository and ask them to fix it. Meanwhile, a workaround we can do is to manually show and hide the bar by ourselves.

```r
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(waiter)
library(shinyjs)
new_choices <- setNames(names(mtcars), names(mtcars))


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("My shiny app"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Selection",
                         selectInput("x_axis", "Choose x axis",
                                     choices = new_choices),
                         
                         selectInput("y_axis", "Choose y axis",
                                     choices = new_choices),
                         
                         hr(),
                ),
                
                tabPanel("Titles",
                         hr(),
                         
                         textInput(inputId = "title", "You can write the title:",  value = "This is the title"),
                         textInput(inputId = "xlab", "You can re-name the x-axis:",  value = "x-axis...."),
                         textInput(inputId = "ylab", "You can re-name the y-axis:",  value = "y-axis ...."),
                         
                ),
                
                
                tabPanel("Calculations", 
                         hr(),
                         
                         checkboxInput("log2", "Do the log2 transformation", value = F),
                         checkboxInput("sqrt", "Calculate the square root", value = F),
                         
                )
                
            ),
            useWaitress(),
            useShinyjs(),
            actionButton(inputId = "drawplot", label = "Show the plot")
            
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    waitress <- Waitress$new(theme = "overlay-percent", min = 0, max = 10)
    
    data <- reactive({
        mtcars
    })
    
    
    filtered_data <- reactive({
        data <- data()
        if(input$log2 == TRUE){
            data <- log2(data+1)
        }
        if(input$sqrt == TRUE){
            data <- sqrt(data)
        }
        return(data)
        
    })
    
    
    v <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$drawplot, {
        # use notification
        show(selector = '.waitress-notification.notifications')
        waitress$notify()
        for(i in 1:10){
            waitress$inc(1) # increase by 10%
            Sys.sleep(.3)
        }
        
        v$plot <- ggplot() +
            geom_point(data = filtered_data(),
                       aes_string(x = input$x_axis, y = input$y_axis)) +
            xlab(input$xlab) +
            ylab(input$ylab) +
            ggtitle(input$title)
        waitress$close()
        hide(selector = '.waitress-notification.notifications')
    })
    
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
 
        if (is.null(v$plot)) return()
        v$plot
    })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```